# Plotting a function involving an implicit function

Tags: plotting

The function I would like to plot is $e=f(w,a;i,\lambda)$ where $w$ is implicitly defined as $w=g(a;i,\lambda)$ such that $w\geq 0$. Hence $e$ is eventually a function of $a$, i.e. $e=f(a;i,\lambda)$.

Now, I would like to plot $e$ against $a$ with varying parameter values of $i \in [0,1]$ and $\lambda \in [0,1]$.

By referring to [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/226174/plot-involving-an-implicit-function), I came up with the following code:

```
eqn = Eliminate[{e == (w + a (-1 - a w + w^2) - \[Sqrt](a (a - (-1 + a^2) (i + lambda) w + a (i + lambda) w^2)))/(w + a w (-a + w)), -((a (-1 + a^2 - 2 a w) ((i + lambda) w - a^2 (i + lambda) w + a (2 + (i + lambda) w^2) + 2 \[Sqrt](a (a - (-1 + a^2) (i + lambda) w + a (i + lambda) w^2))))/(2 \[Sqrt](a (a - (-1 + a^2) (i + lambda) w + a (i + lambda) w^2)) (w + a w (-a + w))^2)) == 1/w ((w + a (-1 - a w + w^2) - \[Sqrt](a (a - (-1 + a^2) (i + lambda) w + a (i + lambda) w^2)))/(w + a w (-a + w)))}, w] // Simplify

Manipulate[ContourPlot[Evaluate@eqn, {a, 0, 1}, {e, 0, 1}, FrameLabel -> {"a", "e"}], {{i, 0.1}, 0, 1}, {{lambda, 0.1}, 0, 1}]
```

It runs forever without results.

I also tried an alternative way, incorporating `eqn` directly into `Manipulate` as follows:

```
Manipulate[ContourPlot[Evaluate@Eliminate[{e == (w + a (-1 - a w + w^2) - \[Sqrt](a (a - (-1 + a^2) (i + lambda) w + a (i + lambda) w^2)))/(w + a w (-a + w)), -((a (-1 + a^2 - 2 a w) ((i + lambda) w - a^2 (i + lambda) w + a (2 + (i + lambda) w^2) + 2 \[Sqrt](a (a - (-1 + a^2) (i + lambda) w + a (i + lambda) w^2))))/(2 \[Sqrt](a (a - (-1 + a^2) (i + lambda) w + a (i + lambda) w^2)) (w + a w (-a + w))^2)) == 1/w ((w + a (-1 - a w + w^2) - \[Sqrt](a (a - (-1 + a^2) (i + lambda) w + a (i + lambda) w^2)))/(w + a w (-a + w)))}, w], {a, 0, 1}, {e, 0, 1}, FrameLabel -> {"a", "e"}], {{i, 0.1}, 0, 1}, {{lambda, 0.1}, 0, 1}]
```

This time, I get a result quite quickly but the plot is empty like this:

[image]

Comment: **It runs forever** How long did it take for just `eqn` to produce a result? for me, its been running for 2 mins now. This has nothing to do with Manipulate, only the `eqn` line itself.  So is the problem with the `eqn` taking long time itself, or is the problem with Manipulate taking long time?

Comment: @Nasser: I've been running both `eqn` and `Manipulate` together, so I'm not sure which is causing the problem. I just tried running `eqn` alone and it is still running for 3 mins now.

Comment: I think you should try each command on its own to see where the problem is. If you run 10 commands together and it takes long time, how will you know which one of these 10 commands is the problem? I think this problem has nothing to do with Manipulate. It is your `eqn` itself which is the problem. This makes it easier to focus on the cause of the problem.

Comment: @Nasser: Yes, it makes sense. But I cannot see what is wrong with `eqn` as it is similar to the code in the link and each of the two functions in it has no problem. Can you please help me identify the problem in `eqn`? Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

eqns = {e == (w + 
       a (-1 - a w + 
          w^2) - √(a (a - (-1 + a^2) (i + lambda) w + 
            a (i + lambda) w^2)))/(w + 
       a w (-a + 
          w)), -((a (-1 + a^2 - 2 a w) ((i + lambda) w - a^2 (i + lambda) w + 
           a (2 + (i + lambda) w^2) + 
           2 √(a (a - (-1 + a^2) (i + lambda) w + 
                 a (i + lambda) w^2))))/(2 √(a (a - (-1 + a^2) (i + 
                 lambda) w + a (i + lambda) w^2)) (w + a w (-a + w))^2)) == 
    1/w ((w + 
         a (-1 - a w + 
            w^2) - √(a (a - (-1 + a^2) (i + lambda) w + 
              a (i + lambda) w^2)))/(w + a w (-a + w))), 
   0 <= i <= 1, 0 <= lambda <= 1, 0 <= a <= 1, 0 <= e <= 1,
   w >= 0};
```

Solving for `e`,

```
sol[i_, lambda_, a_] =
 SolveValues[eqns, e, {w}, Reals] // Normal

(* {Root[-2 - 12 a^2 - 2 a^4 - i - 14 a^2 i - a^4 i - 4 a^2 i^2 - lambda - 
    14 a^2 lambda - a^4 lambda - 8 a^2 i lambda - 
    4 a^2 lambda^2 + (12 + 56 a^2 + 12 a^4 + 6 i + 60 a^2 i + 6 a^4 i + 
       16 a^2 i^2 + 6 lambda + 60 a^2 lambda + 6 a^4 lambda + 
       32 a^2 i lambda + 16 a^2 lambda^2) #1 + (-28 - 92 a^2 - 28 a^4 - 
       12 i - 80 a^2 i - 12 a^4 i - 16 a^2 i^2 - 12 lambda - 80 a^2 lambda - 
       12 a^4 lambda - 32 a^2 i lambda - 16 a^2 lambda^2) #1^2 + (32 + 
       56 a^2 + 32 a^4 + 10 i + 28 a^2 i + 10 a^4 i + 10 lambda + 
       28 a^2 lambda + 10 a^4 lambda) #1^3 + (-18 - 18 a^4 - 3 i + 6 a^2 i - 
       3 a^4 i - 3 lambda + 6 a^2 lambda - 3 a^4 lambda) #1^4 + (4 - 8 a^2 + 
       4 a^4) #1^5 &, 1]} *)
```

Plotting,

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[Evaluate@sol[i, lambda, a], {a, 0, 1},
  PlotRange -> {0.4, 0.7},
  PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.05],
  Frame -> True,
  FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {"a", "e"})],
 {{i, 0.1}, 0, 1, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{lambda, 0.1}, 0, 1, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Bob Hanlon, thank you so much! Do you know how to make the range of the vertical axis of the plot to be in $[0,1]$?

Comment: The small change in the curves when the parameters were changed was due to the plot range changing. Fixing the plot range lets you see the changes more clearly.

Comment: Bob, may I ask you once more on how to fix the range of the vertical axis to be in [0,1]? I tried to add `{e,0,1}` in `Plot`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: I added `PlotRange -> {0.4, 0.7}` to keep the range constant so you would see the movement more clearly. Change that to  `PlotRange -> {0, 1}`

Comment: Thank, Bob! May I ask your help once more? This time I tried to plot $\frac{e}{w}$ instead of $e$. I was able to slightly adjust your code to do this but it runs forever. I added this question by editing my question, and there you can see my code.

Comment: You should ask a new question. Include all required info in the new question. Show what you have tried and explain the problem you are having. Link back to this question as background.