# Plotting with implicit function

Tags: plotting, manipulate

I have a problem similar to [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/278490/plot-with-implicit-function). I followed the solution therein but my problem is still not resolved.

I have an implicit function, $F(e,w;a,i,b,n)=0$ that implicitly yields $e$ has a function of $w$ along with the parameters, $a$, $i$, $n$, and $b$, i.e. $e = e(w;a,i,n,b)$. Next, $w$ is also endogenously determined as the solution of $\frac{\partial e}{\partial w} = \frac{e}{w}$. The relevant ranges are: $0\leq e \leq 1 $, $w \geq 0 $, $0\leq a \leq 1 $, $0\leq i \leq 1 $, $0\leq b \leq 1 $, $n \geq 0 $.

I would like to produce two diagrams. First, a plot of $e$ against $w$ for three different values of $a$, $a=0.1$, $a=0.5$, $a=0.9$, for given $i=0.1$, $b=0.7$, $n=1$. It would look something like:
[image]

Second, I would like to plot $\frac{w}{ae}$ against $a$ for varying parameter values of $i=[0,1]$, $b=[0,1]$, and $n=1$, using `Manipulate`.

My code is the following:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
n = 1
eqns[i_, b_] = {D[w - 1/((1 - e) w), e] == D[1 - e, e] ((-((-a (i + ((1 - e) n (w/(b e^b))^(1/(b - 1)))/(1 - n e (w/(b e^b))^(1/(b - 1)))) + (-1 + a^2) (-1 + e)^2 w - a (-1 + e) (i + ((1 - e) n (w/(b e^b))^(1/(b - 1)))/(1 - n e (w/(b e^b))^(1/(b - 1)))) w^2)/(a (-1 + e) i (1 - e + i + ((1 - e) n (w/(b e^b))^(1/(b - 1)))/(1 - n e (w/(b e^b))^(1/(b - 1)))) w))) - (-((-a ((1 - e) n (w/(b e^b))^(1/(b - 1)))/(1 - n e (w/(b e^b))^(1/(b - 1))) + (-1 + a^2) (-1 + e) (-1 + e - i) w - a (-1 + e) ((1 - e) n (w/(b e^b))^(1/(b - 1)))/(1 - n e (w/(b e^b))^(1/(b - 1)))w^2)/(a (-1 + e) i (1 - e + i + ((1 - e) n (w/(b e^b))^(1/(b - 1)))/(1 - n e (w/(b e^b))^(1/(b - 1)))) w)))), D[e, w] == e/w, r == w/a e, 0 <= i <= 1, 0 <= a <= 1, 0 <= e <= 1, w >= 0, 0 <= b <= 1}
Plot[Evaluate@Table[e, {a, {0.1, 0.5, 0.9}}], {w, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}, PlotLabels -> {"a=0.1", "a=0.5", "a=0.9"}, AxesLabel -> {w, e}]
Manipulate[Module[{i = Rationalize[iv], b = Rationalize[bv]}, sol = SolveValues[eqns[i, b], r, {e, w}, Reals]; Plot[Evaluate@sol, {a, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {0, 23}, PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.05], Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {"w/(ae)", HoldForm[w/(a e)]})]] // Quiet, {{iv, 0.1, "i"}, 0, 1, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{bv, 0.1, "b"}, 0, 1, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, SynchronousUpdating -> False, TrackedSymbols :> All]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.2.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (January 27, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

n = 1;
eqns[i_, b_] = {D[w - 1/((1 - e) w), e] == 
    D[1 - e, e] ((-((-a (i + ((1 - e) n (w/(b e^b))^(1/(b - 1)))/(1 - 
                   n e (w/(b e^b))^(1/(b - 1)))) + (-1 + a^2) (-1 + e)^2 w - 
             a (-1 + e) (i + ((1 - e) n (w/(b e^b))^(1/(b - 1)))/(1 - 
                   n e (w/(b e^b))^(1/(b - 1)))) w^2)/(a (-1 + e) i (1 - e + 
               i + ((1 - e) n (w/(b e^b))^(1/(b - 1)))/(1 - 
                  n e (w/(b e^b))^(1/(b - 1)))) w))) - (-((-a ((1 - 
                   e) n (w/(b e^b))^(1/(b - 1)))/(1 - 
                 n e (w/(b e^b))^(1/(b - 1))) + (-1 + a^2) (-1 + e) (-1 + e - 
                i) w - a (-1 + 
                e) ((1 - e) n (w/(b e^b))^(1/(b - 1)))/(1 - 
                 n e (w/(b e^b))^(1/(b - 1))) w^2)/(a (-1 + e) i (1 - e + 
               i + ((1 - e) n (w/(b e^b))^(1/(b - 1)))/(1 - 
                  n e (w/(b e^b))^(1/(b - 1)))) w)))),
   D[e, w] == e/w, r == w/(a e), 0 <= i <= 1, 0 <= a <= 1, 0 <= e <= 1, 
   w >= 0, 0 <= b <= 1};
```

Note that `r == w/a e` was changed to `r == w/(a e)` to agree with the use in `Manipulate` and the stated desire to plot `w/(a e)` against `a`.

To plot an implicit equation use [`ContourPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourPlot.html)

**EDIT 2:** The color issues was caused by plotting `eqns[1/10, 7/10]` rather than just its first element `eqns[1/10, 7/10][[1]]`

```
ContourPlot[
 Evaluate@Table[Simplify@eqns[1/10, 7/10][[1]], {a, {1/10, 1/2, 9/10}}], {w, 
  0, 5}, {e, 0, 1}, ContourStyle -> colors, PlotPoints -> 50, 
 MaxRecursion -> 4, FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {w, e}), 
 RotateLabel -> False, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[LineLegend[{1/10, 1/2, 9/10}, LegendLabel -> "a ="], {.7, .4}]]
```

[image]

Since `e` does not have an explicit dependence on `w`, `D[e, w]` is zero and the equation `D[e, w] == e/w` evaluates to `0 == e/w`. This requires that `e == 0` and causes `r` to be undefined. This needs to be resolved before the `Manipulate` can result in a plot.

Comment: @ Thanks, Bob! Do you know why we have extra curves at the top left of the plot?

Comment: Perhaps if you resolve the issue with `D[e, w] == e/w` there would be a constraint that would eliminate that portion of the solution. I have no idea what "endogenously" means.

Comment: @ Bob, thanks! For this issue, I posted another question. Can you please help me with this? I really appreciate it. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/279949/solving-implicit-function-nummerically

Comment: may I ask you one more question? Do you know how to put the legend outside of the plotbox? I google searched for the help for last couple of days but failed to find a solution.

Comment: Remove the `Placed` wrapper.

Comment: thank you very much! May I ask you one more question? The last plot in your answer, the three lines have different colors from those in the legend. They are not matching. Do you know why?

Comment: Don't know why the inheritance didn't work. Just specify them as in the edit.

Comment: thanks for your reply. But I think there is still a problem with the legend colors. I thought the issue merits a separate post, so here it is: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/280160/colors-in-the-plot-legend-are-wrong