# Colors in the plot legend are wrong

Tags: plotting, legending

When I plot multiple curves with `ContourPlot` I get different colors between the curves and the legend. This is an issue that emerged from the Edit part of the Answer to [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/279859/plotting-with-implicit-function). The code is this:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
n = 1;
eqns[i_, b_] = {D[w - 1/((1 - e) w), e] == D[1 - e, e] ((-((-a (i + ((1 - e) n (w/(b e^b))^(1/(b - 1)))/(1 - n e (w/(b e^b))^(1/(b - 1)))) + (-1 + a^2) (-1 + e)^2 w - a (-1 + e) (i + ((1 - e) n (w/(b e^b))^(1/(b - 1)))/(1 - n e (w/(b e^b))^(1/(b - 1)))) w^2)/(a (-1 + e) i (1 - e + i + ((1 - e) n (w/(b e^b))^(1/(b - 1)))/(1 - n e (w/(b e^b))^(1/(b - 1)))) w))) - (-((-a ((1 - e) n (w/(b e^b))^(1/(b - 1)))/(1 - n e (w/(b e^b))^(1/(b - 1))) + (-1 + a^2) (-1 + e) (-1 + e - i) w - a (-1 + e) ((1 - e) n (w/(b e^b))^(1/(b - 1)))/(1 - n e (w/(b e^b))^(1/(b - 1))) w^2)/(a (-1 + e) i (1 - e + i + ((1 - e) n (w/(b e^b))^(1/(b - 1)))/(1 - n e (w/(b e^b))^(1/(b - 1)))) w)))), D[e, w] == e/w, r == w/(a e), 0 <= i <= 1, 0 <= a <= 1, 0 <= e <= 1, w >= 0, 0 <= b <= 1};

colors = ColorData[97] /@ Range[3];

ContourPlot[
 Evaluate@Table[Simplify@eqns[1/10, 7/10], {a, {2/10, 8/10}}], {w, 0, 5}, {e, 0, 1}, ContourStyle -> colors, PlotPoints -> 50, MaxRecursion -> 4, FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {w, e}), RotateLabel -> False, PlotLegends -> Placed[LineLegend[colors, {2/10, 8/10}, LegendLabel -> "a ="], {.7, .4}]]
```

where I plotted two cases, $a=0.2$ and $a=0.8$, for the relation between $w$ and $e$, and the result is this:

[image]

As you can see, the colors of the plots and legends are different, green and orange!

Comment: Recommendation in the future:  Post the *MINIMAL* code that illustrates your problem.  Do we really need the entire complicated equations?

Comment: ...or that the figure is rotated?  or that it has a particular Label?  or the FrameLabel has a particular style?  or that the FrameLabel is explicitly not rotated?  And why or why oh why do you define $n=1$ and then include it in your equations!!!?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be plotting `eqns[1/10,7/10][[1]]`. You are cycling through the non-plottable elements of `eqns[1/10,7/10]`

```
ContourPlot[
 Evaluate@Table[Simplify@eqns[1/10, 7/10][[1]], {a, {2/10, 8/10}}], {w, 0, 
  5}, {e, 0, 1}, PlotPoints -> 50, MaxRecursion -> 4, 
 FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {w, e}), RotateLabel -> False, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[LineLegend[{2/10, 8/10}, LegendLabel -> "a ="], {.7, .4}]]
```

[image]

Comment: thanks so much!